# Load the embedded class directly without the embedding class in Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

I've the following two simple classes, which are exemplary for the structure of my problem:

The first class, which embeds the second one

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {
    @Id
    private String myClassName;
    private String otherField;
    @Embedded
    private List<MyEmbedded> myEmbeddeds;
}
```

And the second class which will be embedded:

```
@Embedded
public class MyEmbedded {
    @Id
    private String name;
    private String some;
    private String other;
}
```

In the real case, both classes have a far more complicated structure, with a lot of more fields and references. 
Due to that, i don't want to load the whole MyClass object, as in most cases I only need one specific element from the MyEmbedded list (in most cases with a read-only access).

On the other hand, setting the MyEmbedded class as a simple reference is no option, as we have some complex queries for the MyClass which heavily depend on the myEmbeddeds, which would mean that we would have to execute multiple queries, which is not wanted.

So, the main question is:

How can I load one specific element of the myEmbeddeds list directly as a MyEmbedded-object, without loading the "parent"-object?

Maybe there is a way by using the AggregationPipeline? ( you can define a "target" class in pipeline.aggregate() method and one can find some examples in the tests of morphia as you can see [here](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation/AggregationTest.java)  but i didn't get that working for my case)

Answer (score 0):

You could query `MyClass` based on attributes of `MyEmbedded` and then use a projection to only pull `myEmbeddeds` from the results.

Comment: But this will also load and map any other `myEmbedded` object contained in the list, not only that one i need (the most time consuming part to get the `MyClass` object will be spent on that list)